# Rubocop line is too long and Use new Ruby 1.9 hash syntax

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubocop

Without adjusting the length in yaml how can I take this line of code down:

```
social_share_button_tag(@post.title, desc: '@post.title', image: ' @post.avatar(:medium)', :allow_sites => %w(twitter facebook google_plus linkedin pinterest), url: tiny_post_url(@post.url_name))
```

Also...how do I deal with: Use new Ruby 1.9 hash syntax?

I know it's erroring with the :allow_sites => but when I change it to:

```
allow_sites: %w'(twitter facebook google_plus linkedin pinterest)'
```

It actually will not display twitter and pinterest. It's kind of crazy.

Comment: (1) You'd want `allow_sites: %w(...)` not `allow_sites: %w'(...)'`. (2) You're saying `image: ' @post.avatar(:medium)'` when you probably mean `image: @post.avatar(:medium)`. (3) Maybe Rubocop wants you to add some newlines to spread that method call over a couple lines.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had used this gem. You can use like the below:

[image]